# Select with limit by grouping

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose, i have a table called `events`:

```
CREATE TABLE events (
  id      integer,
  dtstart timestamptz);

INSERT INTO events VALUES 
(4,'2010-06-29 04:00:00'),
(5,'2010-06-29 13:00:00'),
(6,'2011-07-01 20:00:00'),
(7,'2012-07-03 14:30:00');
```

Having two input parameters `dtfrom` and `days` i need to select from `events` table events with `dtstart >= dtfrom`, where `groupby(date(dtstart)) <= days`.

For example, using the above table and `dtfrom='2010-06-29'` and `days=2` i should get these events:

```
(4,'2010-06-29 04:00:00'),
(5,'2010-06-29 13:00:00'),
(6,'2011-07-01 20:00:00'),
```

I got to this for now:

```
SELECT DATE(dtstart) AS _dtstart
FROM events
WHERE dtstart > '2010-06-29 00:00:00'
GROUP BY _dtstart
ORDER BY _dtstart
LIMIT 2;
```

But i would like to avoid grouping.

I need to fetch events that exist in next `days` days. days should not include days without events.

In other words: fetch events that start after '2010-06-29 00:00:00', but number of different dates they start on should not exceed 2 (or 10, or...).

Comment: what is expected result? `4   2010-06-29 04:00:00, 5   2010-06-29 13:00:00, 6   2010-07-01 20:00:00` ?

Comment: yes, with all other fields i might want

Comment: Please note, that there could be 2 events with on year interval and with no other events in that interval, and having `days=2` i should get all of them

Comment: I don't really understand what `groupby(date(dtstart)) <= days` means. Is that you need all rows where interval between them is less then 2 days? Or you need all rows where same date exists twice?

Comment: I need to fetch events that exist in `days` days. `days` should not  include days without events

Answer (score 1):

I assume, that `dtfrom` is of `timestamptz` type and `days` is an integer.

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you need (also on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/baa11/6)):

```sql
WITH r AS (
  SELECT '2010-06-29 00:00:00'::timestamptz dtfrom,
         2 days)
SELECT *
  FROM events e, r
 WHERE e.dtstart >= r.dtfrom
   AND date(e.dtstart) < date(r.dtfrom + ((r.days+1)||' days')::interval);
```

1. I've used `WITH` query to specify the input parameters;
2. Use `timestamptz` comparison to start the range, 'cos one might specify `08:00` of the Jun/29 and record #4 is not making it into the range;
3. Use `date` comparison for the end of the range, adding 1 extra day to the specified number, as `date()` conversion will cut off hours.

---

Does [this query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/4214e/2) produces the desired output?

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM events e
 WHERE e.dtstart >= '2010-06-29 00:00:00'
 ORDER BY e.dtstart
 LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: there is was a typo maybe with `08:00`, try this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/baa11/5

Comment: @warwaruk, not really a typo. Try changing input parameter's value to `2010-06-29 00:00:00`. I wanted to show that different `dtfrom` values might result in a different sets.

Comment: @warwaruk, Data has not changed as I see it. I've updated the query.

Comment: @warwaruk, correct, sorry. So, query returns what you wanted: rows that match next 2 days, right? Otherwise you need to review the desired output for the changed test data.

Comment: These events (4,'2010-06-29 04:00:00'), (5,'2010-06-29 13:00:00'),
(6,'2011-07-01 20:00:00') are expected - next two days with events: 2010-06-29 and 2011-07-01

Comment: @warwaruk, this is a different thing. Please, update your question, specifying that you want matching and the following 2 *entries* from the events table. Otherwise I do not understand how `2011-07-01` falls in to 2 days from `2010-06-29`.

Comment: It falls into *next 2 days that have events*

Comment: I have updated the question. I don't know the right words to describe the issue. Your last query gives the right answer, but it should give the answer having LIMIT (or whatever) 2